# Linqpad fails to run sample query

Tags: linqpad

As recommended, I used Linqpad sample query "But I don't have Northwind" to create the Northwind.mdf file and the test button worked.

However, when I run the preceding sample query I get an error that

> Cannot execute text selection: CS0103 The name 'Products' does not exist in the current context

Please what have I done wrong?

Comment: Looks like you're not on the same database.

Comment: thanks.  you persuaded me to try again and I realised I had just done the first step of creating an empty database but needed to run the Linqpad query to populate it.